# What are all these large files and can I get rid of any of them?

Tags: hard-drive, memory, disk-space

I constantly am told that I am running out of disk space, even though I almost have no applications (outside of the ones that come with the laptop).

I have Xcode which is about ~10GB, but that is it and it says I am running out of disk space.

I did a search on `All My Files` and sorted by size and I see the following...

[image]

What are all of these? Are they needed or is their a way for me to get some disk space back?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Obviously you have or had an Android SDK installed. These images in the SDK are used to test different android versions on the emulator. Simply right-click one of the file and choose "Show Enclosing Folder" and you will see to where they belong or what they exactly are.

If the Android SDK is still installed, you should be able to deal with them using the SDK Manager.